# Set ngModel binding property within ngFor with different name for each property

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel, angular-ngfor

I have an Angular 7 app in which I'd like to have a long list of HTML input components, each sharing similar styles but two-way bind to a different field of a single object in the Typescript file. I thought that this should be achievable with a configuration array and `ngFor`, similar to this:

**app.component.html:**

```
<div *ngFor="let inputConfig of inputConfigs;">
    <input name="{{inputConfig.id}}" type="number" placeholder="{{inputConfig.description}}"
        [(ngModel)]="inputConfig.bindingField">
</div>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
export class AppComponent {

  public objectToBind = {prop1: 5, prop2: 10, prop3: 30};
  public inputConfigs = [
      { id: "prop1", description: "Property 1", bindingField: this.objectToBind.prop1},
      { id: "prop2", description: "Property 2", bindingField: this.objectToBind.prop2},
      { id: "prop3", description: "Property 3", bindingField: this.objectToBind.prop3}
      // additional fields to follow
  ];
}
```

The problem with this seems to be that Typescript (or rather, JS) did a copy by value in `bindingField: this.objectToBind.prop1`, when initiating inputConfigs. The result is that the input component is not actually bound to `objectToBind.prop1`, but rather to a literal copy of it that nothing references.

Is there a way around this issue where I want to bind to different properties with `ngModel` under a `ngFor`? Or do I have no choice but to abandon `ngFor` and write everything statically in the template? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Btw, there have been some answers that point to using an index in the `ngModel` expression, e.g. adding `let index = index;` in `ngFor` and using `[(ngModel)]="inputConfigs[index].bindingField"`. That doesn't seem to help though.

Comment: You should remove your `objectToBind` and directly bind on your ngFor iteration. You will need a custom `trackBy` function (that you can find in the documentation), but it should work. If not, please provide a [mcve] on https://stackblitz.com so that we can play with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bound to `inputConfig.bindingField`, not `objectToBind.prop1`.

you need to bind `objectToBind[inputConfig.id]` to ngModel.

**app.component.html:**

```
<div *ngFor="let inputConfig of inputConfigs;">
    <input name="{{inputConfig.id}}" type="number" placeholder="{{inputConfig.description}}"
        [(ngModel)]="objectToBind[inputConfig.id]">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can do it this way as long `inputConfigs` have objects

```
  public inputConfigs = [
      { id: "prop1", description: "Property 1", value: 5},
      { id: "prop2", description: "Property 2", value: 10},
      { id: "prop3", description: "Property 3", value: 20}
      // additional fields to follow
  ];
```

*template*

```
<div *ngFor="let inputConfig of inputConfigs;">
    <input name="{{inputConfig.id}}" type="number"[(ngModel)]="inputConfig.value">
</div>
```

and the value will bound to `inputConfig.value` for each object

Comment: I'm not trying to bind to inputConfig.value, but a property that is described by inputConfig